# Как сохранить куки с сайта в отдельный файл и в дальнейшем использовать только их?

Tags: c#, cookie, xnet

При авторизации на сайте выдаются куки, и при каждом запуске программы идет эта самая аворизация. Так вот, можно ли как-то сохранить все куки единожды и потом просто считывать их с файла?
Пишу через библиотеку xNet, примерный код:

```
using (var req = new HttpRequest())
{
    HttpResponse resp;
    req.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.AddHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36";
    resp = req.Get("http://rbc.ru/");
    if (req.Cookies.ContainsKey("uid")) tbInfo.Text = "good";
    else tbInfo.Text = "bad";
}
```

Проверка в коде выдает, что куки есть, но как их все сохранить в файл, не знаю. Пробовал через обычный StreamWriter, но там я не знаю, куда обращаться, т.к. в файле выдает либо булевое значение, либо название объекта/класса/метода.

**UPDATE**
Сам решил, только вот пока не разобрался, как воссоздать их в новой проетке.
Код, возможно, перегружен ненужным, так что если кто знает путь легче и короче, буду благодарен:

```
StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(@"K:\aaa.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < req.Cookies.Count; i++)
{
    write.Write(req.Cookies.Keys.ElementAt(i) + ": " + req.Cookies.Values.ElementAt(i) + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я лично написал код для сохранения кук в XML файл используя LINQ.

что-то вроде такого формата файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <cookies_list>
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="6a64d0796e530a04069945d05c4074ca" c_value="yes" c_domain="www.marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="17.05.2057 15:41:44" c_secure="True" />
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="2b132c80be5271bcd9a0dddcc2f12c18" c_value="yes" c_domain="www.marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="17.05.2057 15:41:44" c_secure="True" />
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="PUNTER_KEY" c_value="A81B639C8F69931DAAD24DE4A8972632" c_domain=".marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="27.05.2016 15:41:44" c_secure="True" />
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="JSESSIONID" c_value="web2~F8D01B04BDE8C9702A1795521E06B218" c_domain="www.marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="28.05.2015 15:46:16" c_secure="True" />
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="afterLoginRedirectPath" c_value="&quot;https://www.marathonsportsbook.com/en/&quot;" c_domain="www.marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="28.05.2015 15:46:16" c_secure="True" />
  </cookies_list>
</body>
```

детали реализации тут:

[Как на javascript + selenium сохранить и потом повторно использовать куки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420616/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript-selenium-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8/439647#439647)

---

А вообще более правильным будет использование ранее созданного профиля браузера. А так как я написал выше -- не делать.