# Как на javascript + selenium сохранить и потом повторно использовать куки?

Tags: node.js, cookie, selenium

Интересует использование чистого модуля selenium-webdriver. Чтобы можно было бы только один раз залогиниться на тестируемый сайт, а потом уже повторно используя сохраненные куки. Чтобы эти сохраненные куки можно было бы добавить на вновь запущенный инстанс браузера.

Answer (score 1):

Лично я реализовывал через написание отдельного модуля-експортера-импортера кук в/из XML файла.

Вот код С# с использованием LINQ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Ifrit
{
    public class CookiesManager
    {
        XDocument xmlDoc;
        string xml_path;

        public CookiesManager()
        {
            xml_path = ParamsLib.BrwsrOptions.BrowserCookiesFile;

            xmlDoc = new XDocument();

            if (File.Exists(xml_path))
            {
                xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xml_path);
            }
            else
            {
                var xmlBodyNode = new XElement("body","");
                var xmlCList = new XElement("cookies_list","");

                xmlBodyNode.Add(xmlCList);

                xmlBodyNode.Save(xml_path);
                xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xml_path);
            }
        }

        public List<MyCookie> GetCookiesForUser(string user_name)
        {
            List<MyCookie> cookiesList = new List<MyCookie>();
            try
            {
                cookiesList = (from e in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("cookies_list")
                               let cookie = e.Element("cookie")
                               where (string)cookie.Attribute("user_name") == user_name
                               select new MyCookie
                               {
                                   name = (string)cookie.Attribute("c_name"),
                                   value = (string)cookie.Attribute("c_value"),
                                   domain = (string)cookie.Attribute("c_domain"),
                                   path = (string)cookie.Attribute("c_path"),
                                   expiries = (string)cookie.Attribute("c_expiries"),
                                   secure = (string)cookie.Attribute("c_secure"),
                               }).ToList();
            }
            catch 
            { }

            return cookiesList;
        }

        public void AddCookiesForUser(string username, string cookieName, string cookieValue, string domainName, string path, string expiries, string secure)
        {
            var xmlNode =  new XElement("cookie",   new XAttribute("user_name", username),
                                new XAttribute("c_name", cookieName),
                                new XAttribute("c_value", cookieValue),
                                new XAttribute("c_domain", domainName),
                                new XAttribute("c_path", path),
                                new XAttribute("c_expiries", expiries),
                                new XAttribute("c_secure", secure)
            );

            xmlDoc.Element("body").Element("cookies_list").Add(xmlNode);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            xmlDoc.Save(xml_path);
        }

        public void removeCookieForUser(string username)
        {
            try
            {
                xmlDoc.Element("body").Element("cookies_list").Descendants("cookie")
                                   .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("user_name") == username)
                                   .Remove();
            }
            catch 
            { 
            }
        }


        public class MyCookie
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string value { get; set; }
            public string domain { get; set; }
            public string path { get; set; }
            public string expiries { get; set; }
            public string secure { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

В таком случае возможно сохранять куки и подгружать в нужный момент вручную по нужному профилю пользователя. Пример самого XML файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<body>
  <cookies_list>
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="6a64d0796e530a04069945d05c4074ca" c_value="yes" c_domain="www.marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="17.05.2057 15:41:44" c_secure="True" />
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="2b132c80be5271bcd9a0dddcc2f12c18" c_value="yes" c_domain="www.marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="17.05.2057 15:41:44" c_secure="True" />
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="PUNTER_KEY" c_value="A81B639C8F69931DAAD24DE4A8972632" c_domain=".marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="27.05.2016 15:41:44" c_secure="True" />
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="JSESSIONID" c_value="web2~F8D01B04BDE8C9702A1795521E06B218" c_domain="www.marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="28.05.2015 15:46:16" c_secure="True" />
    <cookie user_name="SomeName" c_name="afterLoginRedirectPath" c_value="&quot;https://www.marathonsportsbook.com/en/&quot;" c_domain="www.marathonsportsbook.com" c_path="/" c_expiries="28.05.2015 15:46:16" c_secure="True" />
  </cookies_list>
</body>
```

user_name="SomeName" -- имя профиля кук

Можешь сделать то же самое, только на своем язЬІке.

Comment: Зачем столько try-catch?

Comment: @Qwertiy , потому что во время тестирования или после изменения вручную могут появится проблемки с запуском кода. Если добавлял -- значит бЬІли проблемЬІ. А вообще "столько" -- 2 всего лишь =)

Comment: Зато каких)))​​

Comment: Пустой блок `catch` - как правило, очень плохая идея. Если что-то случится - никто и не узнает об этом...