# Что необходимо для корректной работы webbrowser в C#?

Tags: c#, авторизация, webbrowser

Здравствуйте. Что необходимо для корректной работы webbrowser в C#? 
Вся проблема в том, что не удается пройти авторизацию на сайте film4smart.net 
На win7 работает нормально, а на win 10 не хочет, вот я и подумал, что где-то чего-то может не хватать...
Если что, авторизация делается руками, не знаю как можно программно прикрутить куки к веббраузеру.

Comment: Работате с контролом или консолью? Сравните версии .NET фреймворка и браузеры на win10  и win7. Это в принципе все ключевые различия, которые могут повлиять на работу.

Comment: webbrowser в C# - оболочка для COM-модуля, огрызок от IE или EDGE в зависимости от версии Win. С ним очень неудобно работать и тараканов полно. ИМХО, если хотите встроенный в приложение полнофункциональный  браузер - ищите стороннюю библиотеку и не мучайтесь.

Comment: Работаю с контролом.

Comment: Так ведь в win 10 есть и IE, и EDGE... Может конфликт какой-то из-за этого возникает или еще что?

Comment: может и конфликт и еще что-то, я же говорю, в нем много тараканов, разных цветов и размеров. Из первого что приходит на ум - ищите различие в дефолтных настройках контрола и в системных настройках браузера.

Comment: А не подскажете где конкретно настройки контрола искать?)

Answer (score 0):

> Если что, авторизация делается руками, не знаю как можно программно прикрутить куки к веббраузеру.

Вариантов несколько:

1. Создай профиль нужного браузера вручную и используй этот профиль. Куки будут хранится в нем.
2. Сохранять куки в нужный формат данных вручную и подгружать их когда нужно. Вот пример сохранения в XML: [Как на javascript + selenium сохранить и потом повторно использовать куки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420616/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript-selenium-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8/439647#439647)
   Но лучш использовать сериализацию. Проще.

> Вся проблема в том, что не удается пройти авторизацию на сайте film4smart.net На win7 работает нормально, а на win 10 не хочет, вот я и подумал, что где-то чего-то может не хватать...

Сравни версии браузера и вообще толково отдебажся. Проверь стоит ли у тебя последний драйвер под нужный браузер. 
Проблема не в ОСи точно.